# Google Sheets Epoch Time

Tags: google-sheets, datetime-format, epoch

In Google Sheets, while copy-pasting values only i.e `CMD+Shift+V`, of Date Time objects, they are pasted as floats e.g

| Date Time | paste values only |
| --- | --- |
| 04/10/2016 23:58:00 | 42647.9986111111 |
| 15/11/2021 23:58:00 | 44515.9986111111 |
| 25/08/2022 23:58:00 | 44798.9986111111 |

These values look like Posix time, only in days. Is it right to assume that the Epoch used in Google Sheets is

> 1899-12-30 00:00:00 UTC ?

If so, why this choice?

Answer (score 3):

You're correct that Google Sheets' epoch is December 30th, 1899. According to an archived [Microsoft dev blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/erics-complete-guide-to-vt_date), this was due to a bug in Lotus 1-2-3, Excel's predecessor:

> And finally, why 30 December 1899? Why not, say, 31 December 1899, or 1 January 1900 as the zero day? Actually, it turns out that this is to work around a bug in Lotus 1-2-3! The details are lost in the mists of time, but apparently Lotus 1-2-3 used this date format but their devs forgot that 1900 was not a leap year. Microsoft fixed this bug by moving day one back one day.

To be compatible with Excel, Google Sheets implemented the same feature.